# Create clustered bar chart across two columns in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
       type    price1     price2
0        A     5450.0     31980.0
1        B     5450.0     20000.0
2        C     15998.0    18100.0
```

What I want is a clustered bar chart that plots "type" against "price". The end goal is a chart that has two bars for each type, one bar for "price1" and the other for "price2". Both columns are in the same unit ($). Using Bokeh I can group by type, but I cant seem to group by a generic "price" unit. I have this code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Category20 as palette
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, PanTool
p = Bar(
        df,
        plot_width=1300,
        plot_height=900,
        label='type',
        values='price2',
        bar_width=0.4,
        legend='top_right',
        agg='median',
        tools=[HoverTool(), PanTool()],
        palette=palette[20])
```

But that only gets me one column for each type.[image]

How can I modify my code to get two bars for each type?

Comment: Please help me solve this problem

Comment: A small thing, I can't import that palette you are using. `ImportError: cannot import name Category20`  And `hover` should be `HoverTool()`.

Comment: @Khris sorry, i left the hover tool instantiation out. updated. as for the palette, what version of bokeh are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is "wide" format. you want to melt it to a long format first using pd.melt() function. For visualization,I suggest you use the "Seaborn" package and make your life easier. you can visualize every thing in one line.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

your_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'type': ['A','B','C'],
      'price1':[5450, 5450, 15998],
      'price2' : [3216, 20000, 15000]})

long_df = pd.melt(your_df,id_vars = ['type'],value_vars =['price1','price2'])
print long_df

my_plot = sns.barplot(x="type", y="value",hue = "variable", data=long_df)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]
A good post on long and wide formats can be found here: 
[Reshape Long Format Multivalue Dataframes with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000427/reshape-long-format-multivalue-dataframes-with-pandas)

if you insist on using bokeh here is how you do it as renzop pointed out :

```
p = Bar(long_df,
    plot_width=1000,
    plot_height=800,
    label='type',
    values='value',
    bar_width=0.4,
    group='variable',
    legend='top_right')

show(p)
```

Comment: yes cause melt function or barcharts was invented by renzop. I didn't even check that answer otherwise I would have given credit to him. This is just the regular procedure of doing it.

Comment: I meant his long format and wide format argument he has df2 in the comments. The post shows the repetition of some values in df2 which is not the systematic way of going about this problem. I found that @renzop has also talked about melt() in the comments below his post.

Comment: Sohrab's answer actually shows the usage of the `melt` function whereas renzop's doesnt. It was more helpful to me since I have very little experience with pandas.

Answer (score 4):

What you are searching for is a [grouped Bar](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/charts.html#bar-charts) plot.

But you have to reorganise your data a little bit, so that bokeh (or better Pandas) is able to group the data correctly.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'type': ['A','B','C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
          'price':[5450, 5450, 15998, 3216, 20000, 15000],
          'price_type':['price1', 'price1', 'price1', 'price2', 'price2', 'price2']})

p = Bar(
        df2,
        plot_width=1300,
        plot_height=900,
        label='type',
        values='price',
        bar_width=0.4,
        group='price_type',
        legend='top_right')
  show(p)
```

[image: result]

Comment: i see, thank you. but i have a problem organizing my data this way. `price_type` is a property of the column, not the row. your organization is the latter.

Comment: What you want doesn't seem possible with the high-level bar plot, you probably need to go on lower levels of bokeh or create the plot with a different library and import it into bokeh, as described here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/compat.html#matplotlib-seaborn-ggplot-and-pandas

Comment: When you have a pandas dataframe you can always reorganize it until it fits to your requirements, thats what they are made for. (check reshape / pivot). Is the plot how you wanted it?